# What special rules apply to unary & operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Are there any special rules that apply to the unary & operator?

For example, the code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct X
{
    X() {}
    void* operator &() { return NULL; }
};
int main()
{
    const X x;
    std::cout << &x << std::endl;
    X y;
    std::cout << &y;
}
```

produces the output

```
0xbfbccb33
0
```

I knew this would compile and run like this because of a discussion I've had here before, but hadn't I known this, I would have expected this to fail to compile, because `operator &` is not declared `const`.

So it appears that the compiler generates `operator &() const` regardless of whether `operator &()` is overloaded or not. Fine, this makes sense, especially with the sample and output.

The question is **where is this behavior detailed in the standard?**

I'm not looking for answers that re-iterate what I already stated in the question, so please don't explain how my overloaded operator can't be called on a `const` object, because I already know that.

Comment: This is C++. I'm sure there's something of a hidden detail, special rule, edge case or something in the standard that's not well-known but Mr Stroustrup found it useful...

Comment: @H2CO3 and that's what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Sry Luchian. didnt' see the suffix there. It must be covered in both deduction and declaration. I'll go hunting as well. Least I can do considering your the one that pointed out the difference to me =P

Comment: @WhozCraig since you weren't gonna ask a question, I did. :P

Comment: That's slightly worrying, I've got some code that defines operator& but not the const version that clearly is broken and I never realised.

Comment: Ok. i may have been close. 13.3.1 looks *very* promising.

Comment: Its not the override of the operator, its the qualification of const vs. not-const that leads to different behavior due to a potential candidate choice of override *not* being taken because it isn't qualified. I think it may be both (13.3.1 (5) and 13.6) actually.

Comment: @J99: there's a conflict there. The author of a class generally doesn't know whether the user of the class "really wants the address of their object", or "wants the logical address of the object". So, either there's a lot of broken code out there using `&` when it should be using `std::addressof` / `boost::addressof`, or else it's wrong to overload `operator&` at all. Formally it's the former (code relies on `&` taking the address should document that it must), practically it's the latter (people who pass types with overloaded `operator&` into that code violate the implicit interface).

Comment: By all of which I mean, even if you fix your code by providing a const `operator&` overload, someone eventually will call your code broken anyway. They're probably wrong, your code isn't broken in the sense of being incorrect C++, but it breaks a common convention. For example, when someone says "in C++03, how do I pass a vector to a function taking a pointer-to-1st-elt-of-array", and the answer is `&v[0]` or `&v.front()`, that very rarely gets voted down "wrong, must use `addressof`, even a POD class can have overloaded `operator&`".

Comment: It's used in a rather specialized smart pointer class and only used in the same module that defines it internally. I still wouldn't do it like that any more though, it's old code...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

n3337 13.3.1.2/9

> If the operator is the operator ,, **the unary operator &**, or the operator ->, and there are **no viable functions,
> then the operator is assumed to be the built-in operator** and interpreted according to Clause 5.

Comment: I totally concur with this answer. The *viability* is what comes into question, and I believe that is bound by the implicit object argument to the operator, and is covered a little later in 13.3.1.(4-5). Totally the right answer, sir. +1!